# jquery toggle image src attribute

Tags: jquery

When I `mouseover` `.thumb` I want the src to be replaced by `hello.gif` and when I `mouseout` I want the src to revert back to the original value. The first part is easy but for the second part I don't know how to "remember" the original src value.

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    current_src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", basepath+"_img/hello.gif");
});

$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", ???);
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use CSS psuedo classes? You could use :hover, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).data('prev_src', $(this).attr('src')).attr("src", basepath+"_img/hello.gif");
});

$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('prev_src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `data` method of jquery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

```
$('.thumb').mouseover(function() {
    // save the original src here
    $(this).data('src', $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).attr("src", basepath+"_img/hello.gif");
});

$('.thumb').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/StGdt/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small jQuery plugin for this:

```
(function( $ ) {
    jQuery.fn.toggleSource = function(img){
        return this.each(function() {
        if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'img') return;
            var $this = $(this);
            var orig = $this.attr('src');
            $this.mouseover(function(){
                $this.attr('src',img);
            });
            $this.mouseout(function(){
                $this.attr('src', orig);
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You can use it this way:

```
$('.thumb').toggleSource('http://my.site/my.img');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much better

```
$('.hover').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).data('src', $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-hover"));
});

$('.hover').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).data('src'));
});
```

Just put data-hover on imagen

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="" class="hover" data-hover="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
```